# Laravel : Comparing datetime between two table while selecting record

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have Laravel app where i check the thread comment (thread_comment table) created date time and thread (thread table) last visit date.

i will select if any thread comment created date time is > thread last visit date, i will query them out.
The purpose of this is to notify the user how many new comments since their last visit to their thread.

Below is my code.

```
$new_thread_comment_count = DB::table('ap_thread')
            ->join('ap_thread_comment', 'ap_thread_comment.ThreadID', '=', 'ap_thread.ThreadID')
            ->where('ap_thread.CreatedBy', Auth::user()->UserID)
            ->where('ap_thread_comment.CreatedDateTime','>','ap_thread.last_visit_date')
            ->count();
```

My problem is, this doesn't work. If I change the operand to <, it will like display all records, which is incorrect.
Do i need to do any datetime convertion in where clause while comparing datetime between two table?

```
CREATE TABLE `ap_thread`
(`ThreadID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ThreadTitle` text NOT NULL,
`Remark` text NOT NULL,
`CountryID` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`last_visit_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`Thread_StatusID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`StatusID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`CreatedBy` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`CreatedDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
`EditedBy` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`EditedDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
`IsSelling` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ThreadID`)) 

CREATE TABLE `ap_thread_comment` (
`Thread_CommentID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ThreadID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`StatusID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`reply_to` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`CreatedBy` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`CreatedDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
`Comment` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Thread_CommentID`))
```

Sorry for the confusion. The thread table stores all the threads created by the users. Whereas thread_comment stores the comments that commented by other users.
What i'm trying to do is to select the total new comments for every threads that created by the logged in user by comparing ap_thread_comment CreatedDateTime is > ap_thread last_visit_date.

- The last_visited_date will only be updated when the owner of the thread visited the thread.

Comment: You compare date created to auth's id?

Comment: no..im selecting based on logged in user, and the datetime between ap_thread_comment and ap_thread tables..

Comment: Can i see your tables?

Comment: CreatedBy is who created the record...CreatedDateTime is when the record is being created

Comment: So it should be `->where('ap_thread.CreatedBy', Auth::user()->createdBy)`?

Comment: In my user table ..I'm referring UserId ..so only I know the thread is created by which user

Comment: Yes, but when you mean `Auth` it means the exact authenticated person. It only shows the data of the user's that is logged in. Your query `ap_thread.CreatedBy` is not equal to the `Auth::user()->id)` this query means: `'9-14/2015' = 1`.

Comment: hi, i only will show the threads which belong to the logged in user.
in my thread table i have 2 column , createdby (who created the thread) and last_visit_date.
By doing this where('ap_thread.CreatedBy', Auth::user()->UserID), im selecting the thread which belong to the logged in user only.

Comment: Can i see the structure of your database?

Comment: Just to understand: you want to select all threads that get created by the ccurrent logedin user and that are created after his last visit? How should this work? If I create a thread I'm online and visit this - if I logout and login again my last visit is after or equal the created cause I created this thread. Is it me or could it be that you have a logic problem?

Comment: I've updated my table design. Just wondering while comparing the date with operand, will it comparing by string instead of datetime ?

Comment: is anyone has the answer for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it using

```
$new_thread_comment_count = DB::table('ap_thread')
            ->join('ap_thread_comment', 'ap_thread_comment.thread_id', '=', 'ap_thread.thread_id')
            ->whereRaw('ap_thread_comment.created_at > ap_thread.last_visit_date')
            ->where('ap_thread.created_by','=',Auth::user()->user_id)
            ->Count();
```